# How to remove a hstore pair with matching value in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I see on the postgres documentation [site](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) that there is a function that allows you to delete pairs based on matching keys. I am wondering if there is a function / method to delete a pair based on a matching value.

Let's say I have a hstore column on a table with values y => 1, x => 2..

How could I update that field to remove x => 2 based on the value 2 instead of based on the key x.

Comment: If you are actually asking to remove key/value pair knowing only the value then  there in no function for what you are asking. The whole concept is based on knowing the key. Using a combination of akeys(hstore) and avals(hstore) a suitable functions *may* be able to determine the appropriate keys, but care would needed. What should the that function do if the following also existed: *y=>2,x=>1* with instructions to remove values '2'?